# Trying to Find Partially Matching Strings in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a SQL Server database that has duplicate records with slightly different file names. There is a portion of the file name that will match if there is a duplicate, hence the crazy substring function. I am trying to write a query to find and exclude the duplicate records, but am not sure if I am on the right track.

Example of what I am trying to match - the bold portion of the filename. I cannot just find records ending in '.CSV1.CSV' because not all of those records will be duplicates. Ultimately, I’d like to exclude duplicates from a report:

125648-**FILENAME_2021-01-01**1.CSV

876765-**FILENAME_2021-01-01**.CSV1.CSV

Here is what I have thus far:

```
SELECT 
    f.fileName, f.Date,
    (SELECT 
         COUNT(CASE 
                   WHEN f.fileName LIKE '%LEFT(SUBSTRING(f.fileName,8,len(f.fileName)),len(SUBSTRING(f.fileName,8,len(f.fileName)))-3)%' 
                       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) 'Count of Duplicates'
FROM 
    database f
GROUP BY 
    f.fileName, f.Date
ORDER BY 
    'Count of Duplicates' DESC;
```

I was thinking I could count the duplicates to know that the file in question has a match, but there is probably a better approach. I also tried using `HAVING f.fileName LIKE '%LEFT(SUBSTRING(f.fileName,38,len(f.fileName)),len(SUBSTRING(f.fileName,38,len(f.fileName)))-3)%' > 1`.

Comment: Please, provide sample data and desired output for it. It's hard to guess what you consider "slightly different". For me `е` and `ё` are almost the same, but `и` and `й` are not at all

Comment: @astentx Thank you, I should have included that - post updated. Example of what I am trying to match - the bold portion of the filename:

125648-**FILENAME_2021-01-01**1.CSV
876765-**FILENAME_2021-01-01**.CSV1.CSV

Answer (score 0):

If all of your records pattern are like of sample, (desire portion of your file name is started from eighth index)

```
;WITH xQ
AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY f.fileName,f.[DATE]) AS Id,
        SUBSTRING(f.fileName,8,PATINDEX('%.%',f.fileName)-8) AS C
    FROM @database F
)

SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT C,
        (SELECT COUNT(1) 
         FROM xQ 
         WHERE
         xQ.Id <> MainQ.Id 
         AND xQ.C LIKE '%'+MainQ.C+'%') AS DuplicateCount 
    FROM xQ AS MainQ
) AS FinalQ
WHERE DuplicateCount>0
```